# how do I send many argument using proxy provider

Tags: flutter

I need to send data from auth to Products and   when I use proxyProvider  to send argument I did received dynamic error . When there is change in Auth I want Products updated too.

**main.dart**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<Auth>(
            create: (context) => Auth(),
          ),
          ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
            create: (_) => Products(),
            update: (_, auth, previousProducts) => Products(
              auth.token,
              previousProducts == null ? [] : previousProducts.items,
            ),
          ),
```

**Products.dart**

```
class Products with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Product> _items = [];

  final String authToken;

  Products(this.authToken, this._items);

  List<Product> get items {
    return [..._items];
  }
```

**Auth.dart**

```
class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  String _token;
  DateTime _expiryDate;
  String _userId;

  bool get isAuth {
    return token != null;
  }

  String get token {
    if (_expiryDate != null &&
        _expiryDate.isAfter(DateTime.now()) &&
        _token != null) {
      return _token;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: can you add Products and Auth class ?

Comment: yes sure I has edited it bro

Answer (score 0):

I am also taking the same course from Max and just happened to run into the same problem. This is how I solved this for me...

Edit the products class as:

```
class Orders extends ChangeNotifier {
List<OrderItem> _orders = [];
String? _authToken;
void update(List<OrderItem> orders, token) {
_orders = orders;
_authToken = token;
notifyListeners();
   }
}
```

Now change the ChangeNotifierProxyProvider as below:

```
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: Auth(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
        create: (context) => Products(),
        update: (context, auth, previousProduct) => Products()
          ..update(previousProduct == null ? [] : previousProduct.items,
              auth.token!)),
)
```